# breakpoint() using ipdb by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipdb, python-3.7

Is it possible that installing *ipdb* (or some other package written to do it explicitely) will result in `breakpoint()` running *ipdb* instead of *pdb* without binding `sys.breakpointhook()` to *ipdb*?

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/

I'm not asking if ipdb does that or if it will, but if its possible to code that. I know that I can set environment variable `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace`. The question is if its possible to trigger this behavior by just installing `ipdb`.

Answer (score 5):

During the installation one could programmatically create either a `usercustomize.py` or a `sitecustomize.py` in the correct directories and alter `os.environ['PYTHONBREAKPOINT']` in there.

These modules are imported by [`site.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) early in the startup sequence and are suited for this sort of customization. Personally, I've never seen a package alter/create these files so I wouldn't expect `ipdb` to ever do it.

Comment: `usercustomize.py` sounds like a perfect place for this. Unfortunately, on my machines when using virtualenv `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE` is always `False` as if python was started with `-S` option or `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` environment variable was set.

Comment: While site customize is the correct place, it's not really the installer's business to be dumping stuff there. User or sysadmin should do this manually.